# To start using amMaps

Tags: javascript, amcharts, ammap

I tried to use amMaps library to create a map.
Here is my code:

```
<body>
    <div id="chardiv"></div>

    <script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/maps.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/geodata/worldLow.js"></script>
    <script>
        var map = am4core.create("chardiv", am4maps.MapChart);
        map.geodata = am4geodata_worldLow;
    </script>
</body>
```

As result I got a transparent div-block with amCharts logo. What did I do wrong?

Comment: You should probably start with a getting started tutorial: https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/chart-types/map/

Comment: Yes, I will. Unfortunally, my English is not very well yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change your script part

```
am4core.ready(function() {
var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4maps.MapChart);
chart.geodata = am4geodata_worldLow;

var worldSeries = chart.series.push(new am4maps.MapPolygonSeries());
worldSeries.exclude = ["AQ"];
worldSeries.useGeodata = true;
});
```

It should work

Comment: Thank you very much! It works. It's time to learn more about the library :)

Comment: If you find my answer acceptable and it resolved your issues, please consider to mark my answer as accepted.
Thank you.